# MetaData class usage

Tags: asp.net, c, vb.net, entity-framework, oop

I am trying to learn a new framework (i think) and i have got to a stage where im not sure whats going on.

So i created a class and a Metadata class. My assumption was that i would have had access to the properties but of course i havent.

I read this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.aspx and followed the example. All seems correct but how do i get access to the properties in the class? I was going to add them to the Partial class but since the example on MSDN doesnt do this, i think i may have missed the point and where does the metadata come into play?

```
<MetadataType(GetType(CustomerMetadata))> _
Partial Public Class Customer
End Class

Public Class CustomerMetadata
    Public Property Cid As Integer = 0
    Public Property Name As String = String.Empty
End Class
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? It sounds like you're using the wrong feature.

Comment: I was trying to use the metadata attribute in my class to make use of it in the back end i.e <Required(), StringLength(50)> Public Name As String - i was trying to learn how to implement this feature in my apps.